# JavaScript phone number validation using charCodeAt

Tags: javascript, validation

I'd like to validate a phone number input using JavaScript to allow only number input. I prefer not to use regex, so I wrote a function like this:

```
function numberTest(){
 for(var i=0;i<phone_number.length;i++){
        if(phone_number.charCodeAt(i) >= 48 && phone_number.charCodeAt(i) <=57){
                    return true;
                    }else{
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

However it does not work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: regex is always the way to go

Comment: Heh, funny, I think that's a first. I've seen dozens of "Why do you think you need a regex for this?" but never "Why don't you want to use a regex?" :)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because it returns `true` after the first valid character. Neither branch will get past the first character, so you need to only `return` if you find an invalid character. Otherwise, if you reach the end without finding an invalid characters, you can finally `return true`.

Something like:

```js
function numberTest(phone_number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < phone_number.length; i++) {
    if (phone_number.charCodeAt(i) < 48 && phone_number.charCodeAt(i) > 57) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

// Test various values
var testData = ["1234", "12ab", "123451234512345", "a1234123", "123123123a"];

var output = document.getElementById("results");
testData.forEach(function(test) {
  var next = document.createElement("li");
  next.textContent = numberTest(test);
});
```

```html
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `isNaN()` (means *is not a number*) method will give you the reverted result in a simpler way...

```js
var phone_number = "5511112223";
alert(isNaN(phone_number)); //returns false meaning it is a valid number
        
phone_number = "55aa1g11d12223";
alert(isNaN(phone_number)); //returns true meaning it is not a number
```